# Ordernar por quantidades de dias faltando para vencer

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

Tenho esse *script* no meu código:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM os WHERE status2 <> 'Fechado' ORDER BY XXXXXXX ";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro na consulta");
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

$vencimento = $linha["vencimento"];

$a = explode("-","$vencimento");
$b = explode("-","$hoje");
$antiga= mktime(0, 0, 0, $b[1], $b[2], $b[0]);
$atual= mktime(0, 0, 0, $a[1], $a[2], $a[0]);
$diferenca= $atual-$antiga;
$dias = floor($diferenca/84600);

echo $dias = (int) $dias; 
}
```

Onde retorna quantos dias faltam para o x vencimento.
Minha Duvida é como Ordenar a consulta no MySQL por registro com datas mais próximas a vencer.

Exemplo abaixo:

```
 Sendo Hoje - dia 10/01

 data_entrada | vencimento |      Dias

     01/01    |    05/01   |    - 5 "Dias Atrasado"
     01/01    |    11/01   |      1 "Para Vencer"
     01/01    |    12/01   |      2 "Para Vencer"
     01/01    |    13/01   |      3 "Para Vencer"
     01/01    |    14/01   |      4 "Para Vencer"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O campo `vencimento` é a data de vencimento da fatura, correto?

Então a lógica do seu código fica assim:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(vencimento, CURDATE()) dias_para_vencimento
    FROM os
    WHERE status2 <> 'Fechado'
    AND dias_para_vencimento >= 0
    ORDER BY dias_para_vencimento";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro na consulta");
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $dias = $linha['dias_para_vencimento'];
    echo $dias . '<br>';
}
```

PS: Só não lembro agora se `DATEDIFF(vencimento, CURDATE())` retorna um valor positivo ou não. Se for negativo, é só trocar a ordem dos argumentos. :)

Comment: Ola Não tenho muita experiencia, voce poderia me explicar melhor sua consulta? no caso eu entendi (Vencimento , CURDATE()) que é a data atual,'---dias_para_vencimento'-- oq seria?

Comment: dias_para_vencimento é só um alias (apelido) para a quantidade de dias restantes para o vencimento. Depois eu uso esse mesmo alias para classificar os resultados.

Answer (score 4):

Não tem porque você ordenar pela quantidade de dias para vencer, principalmente porque você nem filtra só o que está a vencer. Basta uma ordenação pela data de vencimento. Data de vencimento ou quantidade de dias para vencer produzirão a mesma ordem. Você não dá muitas informações mas posso inferir alguma coisa pelo que utilizou e ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM os WHERE status2 <> 'Fechado' ORDER BY vencimento
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/DueDate.sql).

O resto do código não deve ser afetado, apesar de usar um lógica bem esquisita que pode ser bem melhorada ou mesmo retirada se preferir fazer uma *query* que lhe dê os resultados como deseja.